# Check if vqMod is enabled in OpenCart

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I have a vqmod extension which was developed on OpenCart (lets call it vqmod1.xml), I have my own vqmod extension which I developed (vqmod2.xml).

What I was wondering is there a way to stop vqmod2.xml from loading if vqmod1.xml is disabled?

Is this posible?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that. vQmod's are unaware of each other since, they don't get loaded as such into the system. What you could do is check for a change that vqmod1.xml makes. If it's not present, then don't have the vqmod2.xml code run, but that's quite tricky. It would help more if you explained what the two mods do and why the second is reliant on the first

Comment: Hi Jay,  thanks for the reply.  What I done was I used an if statement to check if the XML file exists. If it didn't then the code simply won't execute. Thanks for your answer anyway :)